# creation of Hourglass errored: transaction execution failed

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

I don't know why I'm getting this error while deploying 2 of my contracts.

> creation of Hourglass errored: transaction execution failed

while code compiles successfully no issues there.
During`debugging` TX it highlights on `pragma solidity ^0.4.23` which means it is not going next to this statement. and in console i get this error:
`creation of Hourglass errored: transaction execution failed`.

`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23

contract Hourglass {

    mapping(address => bool) public administrators;

    /*=======================================
    =            PUBLIC FUNCTIONS            =
    =======================================*/
    /*
    * -- APPLICATION ENTRY POINTS --
    */
    constructor() public    {
        // add administrators here
        administrators[msg.sender] = true;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is a missing `;`, but fixed that it work as expected. Without more details how to reproduce your problem we can say nothing about why it is failing for you.